# strtotime time zone offset with UTC?

Tags: php, wordpress, timezone

The $bet_closing is set to this in the WordPress admin: November 9, 2011 6:59AM GMT

Which is 12:01 am PST (California Time) on November 9th. But I want to be able to add another option in the admin so they can select a timezone based on UTC. In my own state it's UTC -7. I tried this "November 9, 2011 6:59AM GMT -0700" but no go.

```
// Auto Close Bet
$now = time();
$bet_closing = strtotime(get_option('cp_gamble1_endtime'));
if ($bet_closing > $now) { // Betting Open!
    $output .= 'On';
    $cp_gamble1_onoff = true;
    update_option('cp_gamble1_onoff', $cp_gamble1_onoff);
} else {
    $cp_gamble1_onoff = false;
    update_option('cp_gamble1_onoff', $cp_gamble1_onoff);
    $output .= 'Over';
}
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this. If there is I'm all ears :)

Comment: Have you tried a string without `GMT`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tested this (I put the command and the next line gives the result):

```
var_dump(strtotime("November 9, 2011 6:59AM GMT"));

int(1320821940)
```

the same as:

```
var_dump(strtotime("November 9, 2011 6:59AM GMT -0700"));

int(1320821940)
```

But without `GMT` works well:

```
var_dump(strtotime("November 9, 2011 6:59AM -0700"));

int(1320847140)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `date_default_timezone_set()` function to set timezone before calling `strtotime()` function

Comment: `time` is always represented in UTC, since it's always seconds since the Epoch, so it'll always be the same. You want to convert for timezones before or after `strtotime`, depending on how you're using the result.